# Unmount my Windows dedicated drive on Ubuntu pendrive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, mount

I installed Ubuntu 16.0.4 on a USB. I would like to keep my Windows 7 internal SSD separate from all of this to avoid messing anything up. I tried unmounting the drive but it didn't do anything. Also, I unlocked the drive from the launcher and it came back when I restarted my desktop.

What options do I have or should I just ignore it and move on?

[image]

Comment: Please give us more details. Otherwise it is difficult to help. Please describe 1) How did you install Ubuntu (with which tool/method)? 2) How did you try unmounting the drive (and which drive)? 3) How did you unlock the drive from the launcher? - What response did you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: Hey. So I did a full install onto a 3.0 USB. I did this by creating a live USB and installing onto my target USB. It works well I suppose. My home is mounted to the USB. I'm not sure if I'm using the right term. Next, when i boot my USB, i see the desktop as shown in the screenshot, including the 2 internal drives (ssd and hdd). By right clicking the windows 7 ssd drive from the launcher, I see the option to unmount. I did this and expected the drive to disappear from view, but it didn't. It didn't change anything actually.

Comment: Thanks for the description :-) I think I understand enough to answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two main alternatives.

### Unmount succeeds

If the unmount operation in the file browser succeeds with an internal drive, it is not turned off, not 'ejected', but only unmounted. So it is still visible. In this case the eject symbol is no longer seen in the panel on the left side of the file browser.

### Unmount fails

If the unmount operation in the file browser fails, 'nothing happens', and the eject symbol is still seen in the panel on the left side of the file browser. This will happen, if the regular user has no permission to unmount the partition.

This in turn may be because

- some process is keeping the partition busy (for example a terminal window opened with its current directory in the partition). In this case you should stop keeping the partition busy and try to unmount it again.
- the regular user has not [enough] permissions to unmount the partition. In this case it should be possible to unmount the partition with a command line from a terminal window.

### Identify the partition and unmount it with command lines

Start a terminal window. Show all drives and partitions with the following command lines,

```
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
```

Show all mounted partitions with the following command line,

```
df -h
```

When identified, you can unmount the partition with the following command line,

```
sudo umount /dev/sdxn
```

where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number, for example

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

or

```
sudo umount /media/$USER/some-text-string
```

Use the actual text string as seen from the previous commands (with `lsblk` and `df`)

---

The `sudo` command makes you run the following command with superuser permissions. When prompted, please enter the password for your regular user and press the Enter key. The password does not echo (no stars, no dots) to the terminal window, but it works anyway. It looks like this for me,

```
$ sudo lsblk -f
[sudo] password for sudodus:
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes made in live boot systems do not persist after reboots. Also, drives other than the live USB are not mounted by default. What you have is an icon to mount the drive and open nautilus to view them. You need not worry about messing up your SSD