# Lost NTFS Permissions

Tags: permissions, mount, ntfs

So, I have been trying to automount my NTFS HDD in the GUI of the Disks Utility and that worked great, apart from the fact that I lost all write/execute permissions on it. I am new to linux, so I have no idea what Im doing. I tried to undo the automount, but that did not solve the problem. I am using UBUNTU 20.04 to learn C++ coding, and all my projects get saved on that Hard Drive. And since I cant write to it any more, I also can not keep on coding... I have two users, one that I created the Ubuntu in the first place and another one that I use daily. Both users are Admins. Also, I have some kind of dualoot with Windows 10 (I say some kind because I somehow messed up the install and now to boot into windows i have to spam the F12 key when rebooting and select Windows Boot Manager from the BIOS boot options :((. ) I am using a Lenovo ThinkPad x240 with a m.2 sata 125 GB SSD that is shared between Windows and Ubuntu (2 different partitons) and the problem drive, a 500 GB HDD formated in Windows with NTFS.

This is the output of the command Mirabeu asked:

```
xmrsediboss@xMrSediBoss-ThinkPad-X240:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=c24bfc94-09f0-48ab-a6d2-12cddb6a4c7b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=34CD-DCB3  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/C802883602882B8E /mnt/C802883602882B8E auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

Comment: The reason for this is because, since the partition is formatted in windows with NTFS the Ubuntu by default mount it in read only mode because there is a potential chance to corrupt the NTFS when writing to it from Linux. You can read this https://askubuntu.com/questions/927556/unmount-my-windows-dedicated-drive-on-ubuntu-pendrive and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215715/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive-d/1215901#1215901 for more information

Comment: can you send the result of this command: "cat /etc/fstab" to indicate you the options to modify

Comment: Ok so I think I know what happened. I worked in Windows for whatever reason, and then, instead of a restart, I did a shut down and power on. And that does not completely kill Windows, it will still be in some sort of super deep sleep... After having the issue yesterday, I went ahead and booted into Windows because I had to get some work done. Then this morning I restarted into linux and it was back. I will still put the cat/etc/fstab output here so you can tell me if there is something else that needs changing. @Mirabeau

Comment: Here is how I automatically mount (not on demand) all my NTFS partitions (whether USB or internal disks) via /etc/fstab (adaptation of the UUID, the mounting path and the uid/gid user/group options to be done of course) without ever encountering any problems:
UUID=01D64E32A20F4790 /mnt/HDD_NTFS ntfs-3g   rw,auto,user,noatime,fmask=113,dmask=2,async,nls=utf8,windows_names,big_writes,uid=1008,gid=1000       0 0

Comment: additional information, to know the UUID of your partitions, run the following command: blkid